# WordPress, getting intermittent corrupted files in browser

Tags: wordpress, caching, corruption

RE: http://tangosouthlondon.co.uk/

Good evening, I'm getting an intermittent rendering issue in WordPress.
Firstly, a JavaScript file that controls the slider and menus sometimes becomes corrupted but is rectified by a Ctrl-F5, but also some of the gallery files get corrupted when the webpage is rendered:

Left hand-side image is a screen-shot from the rendered gallery webpage.

[image: Left image screen-shot from gallery webpage]

Could it be a caching issue?

Any information gratefully accepted,

Mark.

Comment: This looks like a server issue, perhaps talk to the web provide (unless you are doing something to the images live, like thumbnail generation)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you mean webserver issue or configuration of WordPress?  My server skills and knowledge are limited :(

Comment: Web server  Apache/2.2.13 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.13 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4   FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_jk/1.2.25
cache-control  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
connection  close
content-type  text/html; charset=UTF-8
link  <http://tangosouthlondon.co.uk/?p=253>; rel=shortlink
pragma  no-cache
server  Apache/2.2.13 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.13 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_jk/1.2.25
transfer-encoding chunked
x-pingback http://tangosouthlondon.co.uk/xmlrpc.php @Pekka웃